# Python / Pandas: How to merge rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

After merging of two data frames:

```
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='outer')
```

I have data frame like this:

```
index  x    y   z
  0    2   NaN  3
  0   NaN   3   3
  1    2   NaN  4
  1   NaN   3   4
...
```

How to merge rows with the same index? 
Expected output:

```
index  x   y  z
  0    2   3  3
  1    2   3  4
```

Comment: What happens if the values in `z` differ? Does that ever happen?

Comment: You're merging on 'ID', but it isn't anywhere in your dataframe. Feels like we're missing some data.

Comment: This is an example, in the code I have this column

Comment: @IanS When vaules in 'z' are different, it is still happen

Comment: This is a very simple question (in terms of reproducibility), if you want the best answers, always post a reproducible question. Include original dataframes as well.

Comment: I entirely agree with @pshep. You can have much better and more precise answers if you provide a reproducible input data sets and desired data set.  [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you could take mean on them.

```
In [418]: output.groupby('index', as_index=False).mean()
Out[418]:
   index    x    y  z
0      0  2.0  3.0  3
1      1  2.0  3.0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

We can group the DataFrame by the `'index'` and then... we can just get the first values with `.first()` or minimum with `.min()` etc. depending on the case of course. What do you want to get if the values in `z` differ?

```
In [28]: gr = df.groupby('index', as_index=False)

In [29]: gr.first()
Out[29]:
   index    x    y  z
0      0  2.0  3.0  3
1      1  2.0  3.0  4

In [30]: gr.max()
Out[30]:
   index    x    y  z
0      0  2.0  3.0  3
1      1  2.0  3.0  4

In [31]: gr.min()
Out[31]:
   index    x    y  z
0      0  2.0  3.0  3
1      1  2.0  3.0  4

In [32]: gr.mean()
Out[32]:
   index    x    y  z
0      0  2.0  3.0  3
1      1  2.0  3.0  4
```